# TabPane: Como mudar de Tab ao clicar no botão JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Eu não sei se eu estou no lugar certo mais vai assim mesmo, pessoal eu comecei aprender o JavaFX a pouco tempo e tenho uma duvida, eu queria saber como eu posso mudar de Tab quando eu clicar no botão exemplo: tenho duas Tab que se chama tab1 e tab2 eu queria fazer o seguinte, quando eu clicasse no botão próximo eu iria automaticamente para tab2 eu não sei se isso é possível sera que alguém pode me ajudar por favor.

Comment: Usando a seta para direita/esquerda já troca as abas não?

Comment: troca sim, mas o que eu queria fazer era cria um método referenciando um botão, em vez de clicar na seta para direta ou esquerda eu queria que quando o usuário clicasse no botão do formulário mudasse de tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso o código é o seguinte:

```
// Desabilita a mudança de tab através das setas direcionais
tabpane.setFocusTraversable(false);

// Muda a aba selecionada para 1    
next.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        tabpane.getSelectionModel().select(1);
    }
});

// Retorna à primeira aba    
back.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        tabpane.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }
});
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: obrigado amigo era exatamente isso que eu precisava você não sabe o tanto que me ajudou muito obrigado mesmo, aquela parte que você escreveu " tabpane.setFocusTraversable(false); " eu já ia pergunta como era que fazia para desabilitar as função da setas  direcionais e você logo de primeira já coloca no código até parece que você leu a minha mente :) mais uma vez muito obrigado Gustavo Fragoso.